# How to remove JscrollPane from JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, netbeans-8

I have problems with removing JScrollPanels from jFrame.

This is code for adding JScrollPanel after click:

```
jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

                if(count_games == 0)
                    {
                        Game game = new Game();
                        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
                        game1 = new JScrollPane(game);
                        frame.add(game1);

                        game1.setBounds(0, 40, 1000, 960);


                        count_games ++;
                    }else if(count_games == 1)...
```

and this is code for removing JScrollPanel:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    if(count_games == 1)
                    {


                        game1.removeAll();
                        game1.revalidate();
                        game1.repaint();

                        count_games --;

                    }else if(count_games == 2)...
```

After remove empty wireframe stays in JFrame.
Example:
[Before remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXiQL.jpg)

[After remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHRj9.jpg)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. You did not remove the JScrollPane from its parent container. Maybe you intended to call `frame.remove(game1)` to remove the scrollpane from your jframe?

Comment: yes that will be solution, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
game1.removeAll();
```

This removes all components added to the `JScrollPanel`. If you want to remove this whole panel, You need to remove it from the `JFrame`.

So replace this statement with:

```
frame.remove(game1);
```

Or If you want to make your frame empty call `frame.removeAll();` method.